# handleuserinput in react. How to concatenate [e.target.name] to another string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to set state by appending string 'pristine' after [name].
example: setting `firstNamePristine`, `lastNamePristine` to `false` in the `handleuserinput` function depending on `e.target.name`.

I tried the following using template string in es6, and have tried using string concatenation, but the code does not work with `[name] + 'Pristine'` as a property name (where `[name]` refers to `firstName` or `lastName` depending on the `e`.

```
_handleuserinput(e){
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState{`${[name]'Pristine'`:false })
}
```

or

```
handleuserinput(e){
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState{[name]+'Pristine':false })
}



<input type="text" name="firstName" autoComplete="off" autoCapitalize="off" onChange={this._handleUserInput.bind(this)}/>

<input type="text" name="lastName" autoComplete="off" autoCapitalize="off" onChange={this._handleUserInput.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: When using a variable as a key, the square brackets have to be around the whole value,  `[name+"Pristine"]: false`

Comment: Thanks so much. That works!!!

Comment: Does the square bracket only work in react?

Comment: That feature isn't related to React, it's a Javascript syntax. Here's a link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: Thank you Jayce. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), which were introduced as a part of ES6 syntax. In your case, you could combine these with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const name = e.target.name;
console.log({
    [`${name}Pristine`]: false,
});
```

As you see, computed property names provide the square bracket syntax, and inside it you use backticks to create a template string with a `name` value inside.